# Is there any way to create a timestamp in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, keyboard-shortcuts, google-sheets-timestamp

I use PSPad as a text editor, which allows you to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to insert a timestamp, e.g.:

```
2010-07-17 23:45:44
```

Is there a way to do this in a Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: This would be helpful in using a Google document as something like an engineering log. +1.

Comment: yes, I use google docs as external datasources for websites and would like to be able to timestamp for this reason

Comment: @EdwardTanguay if you by any chance passing by.. you should change the correct answer to the most voted one :)

Comment: Readers are advised to use the [best answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/24692/), even though it is not currently on top.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**I use AutoHotKey to perform this function.**

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a Windows scripting application and language.

The code I use is below, it would be easily modifiable to insert the time and change the slashes to hyphens if that is what you prefer.

```
+!d:: ;Shift-Alt-D: Insert current date
SendInput %A_DD%/%A_MM%/%A_YYYY%
return
```

Comment: yes, autohotkey is my friend, odd I forgot about it for this, I used %A_YYYY%-%A_MM%-%A_DD% %A_Hour%:%A_Min%:%A_Sec% and it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad I reminded you :)

Answer (score 54):

Google Sheets supports the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> is the keystroke to insert time.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> is the keystroke to insert date.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> is the keystroke to insert date and time.

See [Keyboard accelerators, mnemonics, and shortcuts](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181110) for more details.

Comment: This is similar to Microsoft Excel, however, unlike Excel you can't seem to follow one shortcut with another in order to produce a complete timestamp. The shortcut in Google Docs only seems to work when the entire cell is selected, not when it is being edited, so you can only get the date OR the time with this method, not both.

Comment: Nice! Note, this only works for Spreadsheets, not Documents.

Comment: Not working on firefox linux :-( is there a way to get this function through menus??!!

Comment: Don't know when this shortcut was added on the Mac side (been using Command-semicolon to do the date for the past few years), but Command-Alt-Shift-colon does insert the full timestamp for MacOS+Chrome. Assuming the aforementioned Windows shortcuts also work, sans the use of AutoHotKey, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: It is documented in the Google Spreadsheets help section, but does not seem to work, alas... I used the NOW() copy-paste trick instead (see other section).

Answer (score 14):

I created a little script that converts the string literal "_now" to current datetime -

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getValue() == "_now") {
    e.range.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

I find it pretty handy to type `_now` and have it convert to current datetime value.

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events for more info on how to add this to your Google Spreadsheet

Comment: Power to Google Apps Script

Comment: This one should be the answer if considering across all platforms not just for windows.

Comment: @Robert, Isn't http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/24692/10579 a better answer?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't think so as these short cuts only add the date or time. Not the date/time the OP asked for. Read the comments made at the link you provided.

Comment: The formatting of timestamps created with this script is addressed [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/96175).

Comment: if configure on browser I can still use it in the phone app - big plus

Comment: Combined with formatting from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/127432/24323 and im good

Comment: When does `onEdit` fire? During every click on a cell?

Comment: @ceving it fires *after* you finish editing a cell (i.e. hit enter update modifying text)

Answer (score 7):

You can put in a bookmarklet with this location:

```
javascript:var thetime=new Date();var txtNode=document.createTextNode((thetime.getMonth()+1)+'/'+thetime.getDate()+'/'+thetime.getFullYear()+' '+thetime.getHours()+':'+thetime.getMinutes()+':'+thetime.getSeconds()); var myInputNode=document.getElementsByClassName('cell-input')[1]; if (myInputNode.hasChildNodes()) {  myInputNode.replaceChild(txtNode, myInputNode.childNodes[0]); } else { myInputNode.appendChild(txtNode); }; void(0);
```

then edit the cell and click the bookmarklet.

Comment: How do you put a bookmarklet?

Comment: Ruby - you can drag the button I created [here](https://read.pubwriter.com/nowBookmark.md) to your bookmarks bar.

Answer (score 3):

The formula for *current* date-time is `=now()`. This can be used to create a *static* timestamp as follows:

1. Enter `=NOW()` in a cell
2. Copy this value with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
3. Paste into the same cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>  (or equivalents for "paste text only" on other platforms)

Comment: That's not a timestamp though, is it? It's just showing the current date/time when the spread sheet was opened, no?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets doesn't support it, but you can try another workaround without external apps:

1. Insert a comment (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)
2. Copy the TimeStamp from there (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)
3. Delete the comment (Right click > Delete)
4. Paste the TimeStamp (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)

(If you are on a MacOS, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for `Copy/Cut/Paste`, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> for inserting the comment, because <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> is minimizing the window.)

Answer (score 1):

1. In a nearby cell, or within a frozen pane, input `=today()` into a cell to get the current date.
2. Copy the cell, and then use (Paste special → Paste values only) from the edit menu, to get a static date and time, at the time that you pasted the value in the cell that you wanted the date stamp.

Comment: Equivalently, use Ctrl-C followed by Ctrl-Shift-V (without reaching the menu). The same approach can be used with `=now()` to get both date __and__ time within the same cell: this is arguably the easiest way to do this without a script.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this [tutorial](http://www.internetgeeks.org/tech/add-timestamp-time-stamp-google-docs-spreadsheet/), it contains video too.
In the script code, change

```
var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy"; // Timestamp Format.
```

By default it only gives you date, change to below code to get time.

```
var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format.
```

Is this what you are looking for ? I tried it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I also created a script for this, and I wanted a format that isn't available in the default timestamps (such as in `=TODAY()` or `=NOW()`).

It also [grabs the timezone based on the current session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session) (which is set in the Sheet's preferences).

```
function _NOW(input)
{
  // for formatting, see:
  // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
  var timestamp_format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM a"; // Timestamp Format eg: 2019-04-11 12:04 PM
  var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
  return date;
}
```

Using it is easy:

```
=_NOW()
```

To clarify: I did the date formatting manually because the custom date formatting in Google Sheets is a pile of flaming trash (no way to set a custom format as the default, no way to change the order of the date/time elements without deleting everything first and adding each one part at a time).

Comment: This ended up being the same time for every invocation

Comment: @nhed every time this script is called (such as when you open the spreadsheet) it will return the current date in that format as a string. If you want a timestamp that's permanent, never updating, you might put this in a cell and copy the value from that cell, then paste it where you want it.

Comment: I added the script on my desktop browser and the spreadsheet was already open on my phone...  it still was producing on my phone the same timestamp that was on my desktop... requiring that I close and reopen to add a data point doesn't seem practical... I combined your formatting with a different function above to get something that worked for me

Answer (score -2):

`=if(len(A2)>0;if(B2<>"";B2;now());"")`

In Settings, change the circuit solution to 1, and it will work without JavaScript

Answer (score -2):

tanguay, I have just tested this `=IF(A2<>"",NOW(),"")`. If A2 has a value then it enters the timestamp. If A2 is empty then the timestamp is not entered in the timestamp column.