# Pass range in Google Apps script custom function without using A1 notation

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm new to Google Apps script and I would like to create a function for a spreadsheet that sums cell values when the cells meet certain criteria, such as the background color. Moreover, I'd like to pass the range as an array and not using [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) for the following reason.

I found a function that uses A1 notation [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25847). The problem is that when I have it on a given cell

```
=sumWhereBackgroundColorIs("white", "A1:A10")
```

and I copy the value to the right adjacent cell the result will be again

> =sumWhereBackgroundColorIs("white", **"A1:A10"**)

while I'd like to have

> =sumWhereBackgroundColorIs("white", **"B1:B10"**)

otherwise I've always to modify manually the input argument and I want to avoid this since I've to use this function extensively.

Hence I've tried by passing a range as an array of values by using

```
=sumIfBgColor(#ffffff, A1:A10)


function sumIfBgColor(color, range){
    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < range.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < range[i].length; j++){

        var cell = getCell();

        if(cell.getBackgroundColor() == color)
          x += parseFloat(range[i][j]);
      }
    }
    return x;
}
```

but I do not know how to get the cell (i.e. the object of type Range) starting from what I have.

Comment: That's not possible, without the use of an API call. If that happens, you need to use the `A1 notation`.

Comment: I hate to say it, but the script you found is not very efficient. On a few rows, the difference might not be significant, but if you have more rows, say 100, then the difference in processing time is huge. The script I prepared is 30x faster, because it uses only three API calls. The script you found uses for 100 rows, approx. 300 API calls. See my example. The numbers given, are milliseconds.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58179/12075

Comment: try use this: =sumWhereBackgroundColorIs("white", ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A10),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(A10),COLUMN(A10),4))

Answer (score 8):

To @Jacob's claim of impossibility, I refute it thus... (but thanks for the improved speed)

using:

```
=sumIfBgColor("#ffffff", A1:A10, COLUMN(A1), ROW(A1))
```

with the following functions will do what you want.

```
/**
 * Sums cell values in a range if they have the given background color
 * 
 * @param  {String} color    Hex string of color eg ("#ffffff")
 * @param  {Array.Array} range    Values of the desired range
 * @param  {int} startcol The column of the range
 * @param  {int} startrow The first row of the range
 * 
 * @return {int}          Sum of all cell values matching the condition
 */
function sumIfBgColor(color, range, startcol, startrow){
  // convert from int to ALPHANUMERIC - thanks to 
  // Daniel at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3145054/2828136
  var col_id = String.fromCharCode(64 + startcol);
  var endrow = startrow + range.length - 1
  // build the range string, then get the background colours
  var range_string = col_id + startrow + ":" + col_id + endrow
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getColors = ss.getRange(range_string).getBackgrounds();

  var x = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < range[0].length; j++) {
      // Sometimes the cell background is eg 'white' rather than '#ffffff'.
      // I don't know why - I think it's a bug.
      // so we remove that inconsistency with colourNameToHex
      // courtesy of Greg at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1573141/2828136
      if(colourNameToHex(getColors[i][j].toString()) == color) {
        x += range[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return x;
}

/**
 * Takes a colour string and returns it to a hex string. If a non-matching string is
 * passed, it will return the argument as is - for this situation it means that a
 * hex string can be passed to it and be returned as is. This is not for production.
 * 
 * @param  {string} color    Must be either a colour name or hex string of color eg ("#ffffff")
 * 
 * @return {object|string}          hex string of color eg ("#ffffff") or the argument given.
 */
function colourNameToHex(colour)
{
    var colours = {"aliceblue":"#f0f8ff","antiquewhite":"#faebd7","aqua":"#00ffff","aquamarine":"#7fffd4","azure":"#f0ffff",
    "beige":"#f5f5dc","bisque":"#ffe4c4","black":"#000000","blanchedalmond":"#ffebcd","blue":"#0000ff","blueviolet":"#8a2be2","brown":"#a52a2a","burlywood":"#deb887",
    "cadetblue":"#5f9ea0","chartreuse":"#7fff00","chocolate":"#d2691e","coral":"#ff7f50","cornflowerblue":"#6495ed","cornsilk":"#fff8dc","crimson":"#dc143c","cyan":"#00ffff",
    "darkblue":"#00008b","darkcyan":"#008b8b","darkgoldenrod":"#b8860b","darkgray":"#a9a9a9","darkgreen":"#006400","darkkhaki":"#bdb76b","darkmagenta":"#8b008b","darkolivegreen":"#556b2f",
    "darkorange":"#ff8c00","darkorchid":"#9932cc","darkred":"#8b0000","darksalmon":"#e9967a","darkseagreen":"#8fbc8f","darkslateblue":"#483d8b","darkslategray":"#2f4f4f","darkturquoise":"#00ced1",
    "darkviolet":"#9400d3","deeppink":"#ff1493","deepskyblue":"#00bfff","dimgray":"#696969","dodgerblue":"#1e90ff",
    "firebrick":"#b22222","floralwhite":"#fffaf0","forestgreen":"#228b22","fuchsia":"#ff00ff",
    "gainsboro":"#dcdcdc","ghostwhite":"#f8f8ff","gold":"#ffd700","goldenrod":"#daa520","gray":"#808080","green":"#008000","greenyellow":"#adff2f",
    "honeydew":"#f0fff0","hotpink":"#ff69b4",
    "indianred ":"#cd5c5c","indigo ":"#4b0082","ivory":"#fffff0","khaki":"#f0e68c",
    "lavender":"#e6e6fa","lavenderblush":"#fff0f5","lawngreen":"#7cfc00","lemonchiffon":"#fffacd","lightblue":"#add8e6","lightcoral":"#f08080","lightcyan":"#e0ffff","lightgoldenrodyellow":"#fafad2",
    "lightgrey":"#d3d3d3","lightgreen":"#90ee90","lightpink":"#ffb6c1","lightsalmon":"#ffa07a","lightseagreen":"#20b2aa","lightskyblue":"#87cefa","lightslategray":"#778899","lightsteelblue":"#b0c4de",
    "lightyellow":"#ffffe0","lime":"#00ff00","limegreen":"#32cd32","linen":"#faf0e6",
    "magenta":"#ff00ff","maroon":"#800000","mediumaquamarine":"#66cdaa","mediumblue":"#0000cd","mediumorchid":"#ba55d3","mediumpurple":"#9370d8","mediumseagreen":"#3cb371","mediumslateblue":"#7b68ee",
    "mediumspringgreen":"#00fa9a","mediumturquoise":"#48d1cc","mediumvioletred":"#c71585","midnightblue":"#191970","mintcream":"#f5fffa","mistyrose":"#ffe4e1","moccasin":"#ffe4b5",
    "navajowhite":"#ffdead","navy":"#000080",
    "oldlace":"#fdf5e6","olive":"#808000","olivedrab":"#6b8e23","orange":"#ffa500","orangered":"#ff4500","orchid":"#da70d6",
    "palegoldenrod":"#eee8aa","palegreen":"#98fb98","paleturquoise":"#afeeee","palevioletred":"#d87093","papayawhip":"#ffefd5","peachpuff":"#ffdab9","peru":"#cd853f","pink":"#ffc0cb","plum":"#dda0dd","powderblue":"#b0e0e6","purple":"#800080",
    "red":"#ff0000","rosybrown":"#bc8f8f","royalblue":"#4169e1",
    "saddlebrown":"#8b4513","salmon":"#fa8072","sandybrown":"#f4a460","seagreen":"#2e8b57","seashell":"#fff5ee","sienna":"#a0522d","silver":"#c0c0c0","skyblue":"#87ceeb","slateblue":"#6a5acd","slategray":"#708090","snow":"#fffafa","springgreen":"#00ff7f","steelblue":"#4682b4",
    "tan":"#d2b48c","teal":"#008080","thistle":"#d8bfd8","tomato":"#ff6347","turquoise":"#40e0d0",
    "violet":"#ee82ee",
    "wheat":"#f5deb3","white":"#ffffff","whitesmoke":"#f5f5f5",
    "yellow":"#ffff00","yellowgreen":"#9acd32"};

    if (typeof colours[colour.toLowerCase()] != 'undefined')
        return colours[colour.toLowerCase()];

    return colour;
}
```

Comment: Just tried it and it works. Very good to have this answer on Web Applications.

Comment: I do test these things, you know. ;-)

Comment: Thanks pnuts - was just reading through my old answer and thought a bit of colour might help (I guess it won't happen though). Sorry everyone who has to read notepad style answers :-)

Answer (score 4):

Reference: http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/2015/11/google-spreadsheet-sum-of-colored-cells.html

Instead of passing parameters as string to the custom function, following script takes input as a range:

```
/**
* @param {string} color String as background color to be searched for in sumRange
* @param {range} sumRange Range to be evaluated
* @return {number}
* @customfunction
*/

function sumColoredCells(color,sumRange) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var total = 0;

  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        total=total+(values[i][j]*1);
  return total;
};
```

Have a look at the following screenshot:
[image]

Comment: so you do not use sumRange that you pass in your function?

Comment: @ses Google apps script does not provide the range by reference to `sumColoredCells` but by value so `sumRange` is an an array of uselesss numbers, so this answer insteads finds the rang by inspecting the formula of the active cell (=calling cell in this case) to find the range. Using the range here instead of string will cause the formula to change upon changes in the range and allow moving the range around.

Answer (score 1):

The following little script will do the trick.

### Code

```
function sumIfBgColor(color, range){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getColors = ss.getRange(range).getBackgrounds();
  var getValues = ss.getRange(range).getValues(), x = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < getValues.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < getValues[0].length; j++) {
      if(getColors[i][j].toString() == color) {
        x += getValues[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

### Explained

First, the active spreadsheet is determined. Then both the values and the colors, based on the range, are fetched. The values will be used to iterate through the colors and ultimately the summation.

### Usage

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Sum based on Background](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHVfMUczTm9qN2xWSmVYdEZlbTBpc3c&usp=sharing)**

Comment: this function work but you have to call it with A1 notation, i.e. writing on a cell =sumIfBgColor(#ffffff, "A1:A10")
This doesn't fit the requirements I wrote above, namely while copy and paste the formula between cells I'll have to edit the content manually

Comment: @ganswer In my comment to your question, I already mentioned it isn't possible. The code you have shouldn't have worked with or without the A1 notation. Therefore I wrote a script that does.

Comment: sorry I ddin't read your comment. So bad news! So there is no way..I cannot use A1 notation, I will have to change  completely the layout of my spreadsheet. thanks

Comment: @ganswer Did you find my answer useful though?

Comment: it is a good option but I had already a similar function that works with A1 notation. Please modify your answer including at the top a comment saying that what I search for is not possible, so that I can accept your answer as solution

Comment: This post answers the [question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-timestamp-in-a-google-spreadsheet) referred as the OP's code source, not this question.

Comment: @Rubén I'm very confused, this looks like it definitely answers the question  Even if it were incorrect, it would still be "an answer" in terms of the NAA flag.

Comment: @jonsca: I don't think that it answers the question as it doesn't mention anything about the question by the other hand it provides a code that looks to do the same as the code included by the OP. In other words, the question is about how to make able the code to be able to use dynamic parameters in order to be able fill adjacent cells with the same formula but with the corresponding cell references.