# How to send cell as argument for function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I am trying to write a custom function for Google spreadsheets that checks the formatting of a given cell and acts accordingly. I know that I can give a string as argument and get it to work but then I have to rewrite the command for each cell I want to use it in instead of just dragging it out over several cells.

That is, I can write:

```
 =IFBOLD("A1", val1, val2)
```

but I want to be able to write:

```
 =IFBOLD(A1, val1, val2).
```

Now the script looks like this:

```
function IFBOLD(a1Notation,trueval, falseval) {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(a1Notation);

  if(cell.getFontWeight() == 'bold')
    return trueval;
  return falseval;

};
```

Any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

With this little snippet you can do that.

### Code

```
function isBold(startcol, startrow) {
  // prepare string
  var str = String.fromCharCode(64 + startcol) + startrow;

  // retrieve font weight
  var bCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getRange(str).getFontWeight();

  // return true if is bold 
  return bCell == 'bold' ? true : false;
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

In [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50568/29140), Tom Horwood found a way to circumvent the usage of quotes.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Check for Font Weight](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1ZlUGBjClSckZynTBltjQURpdX7UcD0UM8N0_r5lScSk/edit?usp=sharing)**
Add the script under *Tools>Script editor* and press the bug button to activate the authentication.