# Sum cells according to cell colour

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to sum cells only with a specific cell colour.

I'm using this code:

```
function sumWhereBackgroundColorIs(color, rangeSpecification) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
    var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
    var x = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {

            var cell = range.getCell(i, j);

            if(cell.getBackgroundColor() == color)
               x += parseFloat(cell.getValue());
        }   
     }
     return x; 
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: This code does not work. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you call the function?

Comment: Use this code @TomHorwood made: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50568/29140

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass range in Google Apps script custom function without using A1 notation](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50511/pass-range-in-google-apps-script-custom-function-without-using-a1-notation)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that your using the function `getBackgroundColor()` which doesn't exist. 
Use `getBackground()` instead.

And make sure you're passing both range and color code as strings (enclosed with `"`). Also make sure to pass color codes in  lower case ("#ffffff", **not** "#FFFFFF").