# Google Sheets sum-by-color function is no longer working. Possible to update?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

Been using the following function to generate the sum of same-colored cells:

```
function sumColoredCells(sumRange,colorRef,test) {
  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var sumValues = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getValues(); 
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var totalValue = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        if ((typeof sumValues[i][k]) == 'number')
          totalValue = totalValue + (sumValues[i][k]);
  return totalValue;
};
```

As of sometime in the past few weeks, this no longer works and results in a permanent loading notificaiton. I was wondering what broke it and if it's fixable.

Comment: Have you also tried this one: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50568/29140

Comment: Hi. Your script is working fine for me. The 'test' parameter seems to be redundant so I excluded that when I entered the function in my spreadsheet. My formula `=sumColoredCells(A2:A11,C1)` where A2:A11 included several cells of different background colours and values, and Cell C1 had a background of a given colour that was one of the colours included in the range. The sum was accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The failure of that function is due to the regex expressions, which in the script are suitable for countries where the comma is used as a separator.
If you're using another country's settings instead, which use semicolons, you'll need to make two small changes to the script:

**row 5**
from: `activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/)`
to    `activeformula.match(/\((.*)\;/)`

**row 8**
from: `activeformula.match(/\.(.*)\)/)`
to    `activeformula.match(/\;(.*)\)/)`

or by changing the regex to work in all countries by accepting alternatively both the comma and the semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those confirming that formula functions. This was apparently related to an issue with Google Sheets that was resolved yesterday. Marking as answered.