# Insert today's date as a value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, google-sheets-timestamp

I have a Google Sheets where I store customers details and the date of the last time I contacted or was contacted by this customer:

```
Customer name   |   Last contact date
Bob             |   2016/01/30
John            |   2016/02/16
```

I have to update the `Last contact date` cell very often.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to replace the current cell's content with today's date?
Or anything faster than looking at my calendar and typing it.

Obviously, `=TODAY()` is not a solution because it would change the date all the time.

---

Note: Not a duplicate of [How to stop Now() function from auto-updating](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/71099/how-to-stop-now-function-from-auto-updating), which indeed has a solution that *partly contains* the answer to the present question, but is 1) Taken from a radically opposed point of view 2) About timestamps, not dates.

Answer (score 4):

There is a shortcut exactly for this:

- Select the cell
- Press `CTRL` and `;`
- That's it, the cell's content has been replaced with today's date.