# Insert current date to cell based on content in other cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, date, google-sheets-timestamp

**Background:**

I am trying to create a sheet which tracks my costs on daily basis. Instead of entering the current date everyday, I want the sheet to store the current day based on the content I enter in the `Costs` column.

[image]

For the cells in column `C` I use the following formula:

```
=if(D2="","empty",TODAY())
```

The problem with this function is that it updates everyday. As you can see from the picture the date on `C` appears as the most current date although the information there was inserted days ago.

**Question:**

How do I achieve that the content in the cells of column `C` stay only on the date of insertion content to column `D` and they do not update everyday to the current date?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is related to [Is there any way to create a timestamp in a Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4056) so my answer is similar to those, but adapted to your setup.

#### Automatic insertion: requires Apps Script

Use the following script (Tools > Script Editor):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.getColumn() == 4) {
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(e.value.length>0 ? new Date() : '');
  }
}
```

On every edit, the script checks whether the edit was to "Sheet1" (put the name of the relevant sheet here) and to the column 4 (that is D). If so, it fills the cell directly to the left (`offset(0,-1)`) with the current date. Unless the edit removed content from column D; then the corresponding C cell becomes empty.

#### Manual insertion: no script

Make the habit of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> in column C when editing column D. This inserts the current date.

Comment: I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 22, file "Code")`. Any clues why? FYI: I have already a script running on the startup who's task is to take me to the last edited cell, where should I place the new code snipppet

Comment: Did you try to run the script manually? It's not meant for that; the onEdit name means it's run automatically when an edit is done.

Comment: Although the error appears, the code works as expected. It would be great if it could do the reverse as well: When deleting an entry from `D` removing content from corresponding C

Comment: I added support for deletion. Still don't know why you're getting an error; it may be some interference of script functions?  Function are placed one after another in the script file: `function onOpen() ... { }`  `function onEdit()... { }`

Comment: Great! pity I can not upvote 10x :)... I'll ignore the error for now.

Comment: Hey really appreciated for this! :) Quick question! What if I only want to add the date to a cell-based on a specific value, no on every edit? Thank you in advance!