# Time stamp on last row of column for changes in predetermined range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-timestamp

I am looking for a way to add a time stamp to the last row of a column of figures any time there is a change in the above range. I have been able to find a number of examples where you can timestamp the next or last column but none for monitoring a column range and time stamping below. I am trying to get this working across multiple column with the answer showing in the same row of each.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details regarding your research and attempts to adapt your findings. Including a demo spreadsheet having the minimal but complete details could very helpful to minimize the back and forth.

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88502/insert-current-date-to-cell-based-on-content-in-other-cell

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-timestamp-in-a-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the code from [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88510) to fit your description. In the example below, columns 2-5 (that is, B-E) of sheet named 'Sheet1' are monitored for changes. In case of change, a timestamp is inserted in the last row of that column.

To customize: change the sheetname and column bounds on line 4 of the script. If a non-contiguous range of columns is to be watched (e.g., columns 2,4,7,8), replace the conditions `column >= 2 && column <= 5` with, for example, `[2, 4, 7, 8].indexOf(column) > -1`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Sheet1' && column >= 2 && column <= 5) {
    var row = sheet.getMaxRows();
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```