# Google Sheets - Dropdown list populates date in another field

Tags: google-sheets

I have a header with "Status" and a simple dropdown that is Open, Closed.
I am trying to set the next header "Date Completed" with today's date.
Not sure where to look at establishing this kind of process.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12PNvyd9lAvrR1lg2pyMsy-CkJ-cgEu8y49xv9xIVyd4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert current date to cell based on content in other cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88502/insert-current-date-to-cell-based-on-content-in-other-cell)

Comment: Welcome. Your scenario is not clear. Do you mean: when the dropdown value for a given row = "Completed", then you want the current date to be entered in Column B on that row. This requires an `OnEdit(e)` script. There are many (many, many) precedents for this. I have listed one here already.

Comment: "I am trying to set the next header "Date Completed" with today's date." Just to clarify something here for posterity... the date, when it is entered, will be "today's date". Over time, you want the date to remain fixed on the day that it was entered so that you have an accurate historical record of "when" the task was completed. This is the reason that 'today()' isn't helpful because the date would always change to "today's date", and there would be no record of the actual date that the task was completed. This is why you need a script like the one mentioned above.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to read “Closed” and then set todays date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a script that watches for an edit to cell. The script is written as a ["Simple" onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

If the edit is "Closed", then the script inserts the date into the cell adjacent to the edited cell.

The script uses [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to get the range and the value of the edited cell.

The desired value ("Closed") of the edited cell is described as a variable.

An If statement tests whether the edited value is equal to "Closed"; if this is true, then the script inserts the current date into the cell on the same row, one column to the right of the edited cell. The script uses `offset(Row,Column)` [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) to define the new range.

The script includes two options for the date.

- **Option#1** (currently remmed out): inserts inserts the date; this means that you should format the cell/column to whatever format you require.
- **Option#2** formats the date within the code so that the date inserted into the cell is preformatted. You can edit the code to format the data in whatever way suits you.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var evalValue = "Closed";
  var range = e.range;
  var editedvalue = e.value;
  
  if (editedvalue === evalValue){
    // the edited cell is equal to "Closed".
    // so make cell on same row and one cell to right = date.
    // Option#1 - format the cell/column however you like it
    // range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
    // Option#2 - set the format in the code; you can additional formatting this this setting
    // refer "formatDate(date, timeZone, format)"
    // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    range.offset(0,1).setValue(formattedDate);
  }
}
```