# How to add current date to cell if the rest of the cells (or some cells) in that row are edited, but only the first time?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I have a column A4:A (heading = Date), and other columns after it B4:O.

I want column A to fill in today's date automatically when I fill in any other columns (some of these B4:O maybe empty, but most will be filled) in that row. But I only want that to happen the first time I edit any other columns within that row.

What I've tried:

```
A7: =IF(B7 > 0,TODAY(),)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is similar to [Is there any way to create a timestamp in a Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4056) except here you want to date of the first edit, not the most recent one.

- This **cannot** be achieved with spreadsheet formulas, because if a formula inserts today's date subject to some condition (nonempty cells), it will also insert tomorrow's date tomorrow, if the condition still holds.
- This can be done  **manually**, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> (Control/Command and semicolon) in Column A after making the first edit to a row.
- Or this can be done **automatically by a script**.

Such as this one, which inserts the date of *first edit* to a row in the first column of that row. The date is inserted in ISO format yyyy-MM-dd. (It can be any other format supported by [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var dateCell = e.range.getSheet().getRange(row, 1);
  if (!dateCell.getValue()) {
    dateCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  }
}
```

The script should be entered in Tools > Script Editor. It runs automatically on every edit, but it will not replace the date in column A if it's already there.

To have a script recording the date of *last* edit, change it

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var dateCell = e.range.getSheet().getRange(row, 1);
  dateCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Comment: what does `e` in `onEdit(e)` means?

Answer (score -1):

In cells from column A you type:

**A2:** *=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",NOW())*

You must format column like date

Comment: This will keep the column A changing on every edit, it does not record the time a particular row was edited.